# Calculate the pitch for cudaMalloc as in cudaMallocPitch

Tags: c++, cuda

Simple question:
Is it possible to compute or get the best pitch for an array without allocating memory as in

```
cudaMallocPitch(void** p, size_t *pitch, size_t width, size_t height)
```

I would like to get the pitch, without allocating the memory and then use the function cudaMalloc instead!

(this is crucial if one wants to implement some caching allocator for pitched allocations for the cuda platform)

Is it:

```
// round width to next mulitple of  prop.textureAlignment;  
size_t proper_pitch = ((width / (size_t)device.m_prob.textureAlignment) + 1) * device.m_prob.textureAlignment;
```

**Update:**
I now calculate the proper_pitch as the smallest  upper multiple of 32/64/128 bytes:
I have no tried this, and I still don't know what else the runtime API could do, maybe look at the already allocated memory and do some fitting? In the CUDA Programming Guide, for fully-coalesced access the above is a necessary requirement (not sufficient, since at runtime warps need to access continously)...

```
// use Cuda Programming Guide Alignmenet (which should be the best i think)
    // Upper closest multible of 32/64/128
    //size_t upperMultOf32 = ((widthInBytes + 32 - 1)/32)*32;   //  ((widthInBytes-1)/32 + 1)*32
    proper_pitch = std::min(
                        std::min( ((widthInBytes + 32 - 1)>>5)<<5 , ((widthInBytes + 64 - 1)>>6)<<6 ), 
                        ((widthInBytes + 128 - 1)>>7)<<7
                    );
```

Comment: You can do this: `size_t proper_pitch = ((width + device.m_prob.textureAlignment - 1) / device.m_prob.textureAlignment) * device.m_prob.textureAlignment;`

Comment: The problem is that texture alignment is not the only constraint that the CUDA driver takes into account when doing pitched allocations.. the 2D copy engine has alignment constraints that may differ from the texture pipeline. If NVIDIA doesn't already support it, it'd be easy for them to enable callers to pass NULL for the pointer passback when the caller only wants to know the pitch of a hypothetical allocation. In fact you should try that and let us know if it works : - )

Comment: I will definitely try this :-)

Comment: OK, sadly, this will definitely not work, calling `cudaMallocPitch(0, pitch,widthInBytes,height)` will fail due to a nullptr input with CUDA 5

Answer (score 3):

At present there is no way of obtaining the pitch calculation. The details are probably hardware version specific, and NVIDIA have neither documented the calculations, nor exposed the calculations via an API (although, as pointed out it would be trivial for them to do so).

If this is a serious limitation for a real world use-case, I would recommend raising a bug report/feature request via the NVIDIA registered developer's portal. In my experience, they do listen to serious feature requests.

[This answer was assembled mostly from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered list]